# How get id from dynamic button ? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this xpath element who change dynamically, and i like to click on it, how i can do it?

```
//*[@id="/api/services/61_ellipsis"]
```

The button HTML is:

```
<button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default" id="/api/services/33_ellipsis">
    <span class="v-btn__content">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-dots-vertical theme--light">
        </i>
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: can you post your html source?

Comment: <button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default" id="/api/services/33_ellipsis"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-dots-vertical theme--light"></i></span></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID changes dynamically, you cannot use the exact ID to get the element, but a `contains` query might work

Query on any element that contains `api/services` in the ID:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'api/services')]
```

Query on the button without any ID info. Has inner `span` and `i` elements:

```
//button[span/i]
```

Query on button element that contains `api/services` in the ID, and also has inner `span` and `i` elements:

```
//button[span/i and contains(@id, 'api/services')]
```

To save the ID, you want to find the element then get it's ID attribute:

```
buttonId = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[span/i and contains(@id, 'api/services')]").get_attribute("id")
```

Comment: this is the html :
<button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default" id="/api/services/33_ellipsis"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-dots-vertical theme--light"></i></span></button>

Comment: @FlutterLover I've updated my post with a few options you can try.

Comment: It's working fine, but it select the first menu, my question how to save the id as a variable and i can after click on it and delete it ?

Comment: In my exemple how to save the number 61 as id and after i click just on //*[@id="/api/services/id_ellipsis"] ?

Comment: @FlutterLover You won't be able to find the element the first time by it's exact ID since it is dynamic as you said. But, you can find the element using partial ID (like example I posted), then you can call `get_attribute("id")` to access the ID like that. I updated my example with code to do this.

Comment: Working fine, just my last question how i can print this ID ?

Comment: @FlutterLover `print(buttonId)` should work for you.

Comment: He give me this : [100%]/api/services/33_ellipsis

Comment: Finaly i have the solution :
`buttonId.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: @FlutterLover Yes that's right, calling a split on `/` and getting the last item in the list should get you the ID. Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christine you are the best

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.v-btn.v-btn--flat.v-btn--icon.v-btn--round.theme--light.v-size--default[id^='/api/services/'] > span.v-btn__content > i.v-icon.notranslate.mdi.mdi-dots-vertical.theme--light"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='v-btn v-btn--flat v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default' and starts-with(@id, '/api/services/')]/span[@class='v-btn__content']/i[@class='v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-dots-vertical theme--light']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```